# Is there a technique to find the boundaries of two 'splashes' on the graph?

Tags: python, algorithm, function, math, time-series

Ok, so I am looking for an algorithm that can calculate the boundaries of two 'splashes' that are depicte on the following graph. [This is the graph. We can observe here two 'splashes' in the middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w7OK.png)

So I was trying to solve this with the derivative but it only worked when there is one splash, not two or more. If you worked with time-series or just know how to find the asnwer, please, feel free to write below. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to move two points along a line with a small horizontal offset between them. You can use these points to calculate local slope, and when the slope exceeds a threshold, mark the location between the points as a "boundary" by adding it to a boundary list.